# Is Castelnuovo bound tight?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Castelnuovo bound says that if we have a function field(algebraic curve) $F$ and a divisor on it $D$ then: 
$g\leq c\frac{\deg(D)^2}{\ell(D)}$(where $c$ is some global constant say 2 and $g$ is a genus of the curve). I would like to ask if the converse is true?  My question is if the converse is true for every  $\ell(D)$? 
Formally the question is the following:

Does there exists a constant $c$ such that for every function field $F$ and for every integer $2\leq l \leq g$  there exists a divisor $D$ with $\ell(D)= l$ and $g\geq c\frac{\deg(D)^2}{\ell(D)}$?

Comment: I removed the "l-functions" tag, since $\ell(D)$ has nothing to do with L-functions.

The implication `$\deg(D) \le \sqrt{g} \Longrightarrow \ell(D) \le 1$` is wrong in general: for a hyperelliptic curve, with $D$ twice a Weierstrass point, we have $\ell(D) = 2$ and $\deg(D) = 2$, which is $\le \sqrt{g}$ for $g$ sufficiently large.

Answer (score 6):

Over an algebraically closed field, the general curve of genus $g$ has a divisor of degree $d$ and (projective) dimension $r = l(D) - 1$ if and only if $r(d − r + 1) − (r − 1)g \ge 0$. This is the main result of Brill-Noether theory.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brill%E2%80%93Noether_theory

Over non-algebraically closed fields the answer to your question is probably no, in general.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I agree that if $r(d−r+1)−(r−1)g \geq 0$ then there exists a divisor but I think that it the converse is not true. It may happen that 
$r(d−r+1)−(r−1)g <0$ and still you will have divisor of degree $d$ and dimenion $r+1$. 
Over general curve we usually have divisor of degree $2\sqrt{g}$ with r=2. Taking $g$ large we will get that your equation is neggative 

Comment: If $r(d−r+1)−(r−1)g < 0$ then there exists a curve of that genus that has no divisor with those parameters. In fact this will be true for "most" curves.

Comment: What you said about $r=2$ is false. You may be thinking of smooth plane curves, but most curves are not like that.